# JavaScript OSX MouseWheel Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, macos, mousewheel

Using the JavaScript MouseWheel on OSX seems to be not useable for precise stepped scrolling.

Any idea how to fix this example for OSX:

http://jsfiddle.net/daslicht/Qbq4k/

The issue is that, on OSX multiple MouseWheel Events get dispatched. 
I only need to touch the MouseWheel of my Logitech Anywhere MX Mouse
and 3 or more events get dispatched.

When I try to scroll the list with the Touchpad, 
precise scrolling is impossible due to the excessive MouseWheel Events.

On Windows scolling the List, works like a charm, 
since only ONE Event get dispatched on each MouseWheel Step 
(even in hyperscrolling Mode of the Anywhere Mouse)

I have even tried to block the incoming events 
or lower the threshhold but nothing worked as nice as on Windows:

http://jsfiddle.net/daslicht/Qbq4k/ //blocking events after the first incoming for n ms

How do you guys deal with the MouseWheel on OSX?

```
if(osx){
   mouse=false; //?
}
```